# Require Max Value of previous 5 high values : Based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, series

I need help in the following code for finding the max value in the window of previous 5 rows. i don't why its not working. Could anyone please help?
I am trying to put the conditions as:
if day(1), then max value = value[day(1)]
elif day(1<n<=5), then max value = value[day(n)] if value[day(n)]>value[day(n-1)]
else, max value will be the last max value iterated. Thanks for your time. Also, len(src) is 29969, if required.

```
def high_change(src, lkbk) :
    highest_high = []
    last_val = np.nan

    for i in range(len(src)) :
        for a in range(i, i+lkbk) :
            if a == i : 
                highest_high = high_df1[a] # first day value is max value
                last_val = high_df1[a]
            elif high_df1[a] > high_df1[(a-1)] :
                highest_high = high_df1[a] # then max high value in ref to previous value.
            else :
                highest_high = last_val
    
    return highest_high

df1['h_h']  = pd.Series(perc_change(df1, 5))
```

[image: Please see here the desired output]

Comment: Your conditions are not clear. For instance, could you explain 14023 from line 9 (14020) for a better understanding, please?

Comment: sorry, if my question was not that explainatory,

line 9 output 14023
input rows, 4 to 8
on 4th day, high value = 14019 ;
from 4th to 5th = high value unchanged since current < previous ;
5th to 6th = high value changed = 14022 since now current>previous ;
6th to 7th = high value changed = 14023 since current>previous ;
7th to 8th = high value unchanged = 14023

Comment: Why is the output on line 5 14019 and not 14021 (which is a higher value from line 1)?

Comment: because on the last day of 5-day period, the value increased from its previous day's value. so i want to take that value as max now.

Comment: @r_goel. I have forgotten to update the output. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First, compute if the value of current day is greater than the value of the previous day. Apply `cumsum` to get increasing values and `rolling` with a window of 6 (last 5 previous days and the current one). Finally, get the max value of the window excluding the current day:

```
WINDOW = 5
df['highest5'] = df['high'].gt(df['high'].shift()).cumsum() \
                           .rolling(WINDOW+1) \
                           .apply(lambda x: df.loc[x[:WINDOW].idxmax(), 'high'])
```

```
>>> df
     high  highest5
0   13996       NaN
1   14021       NaN
2   14019       NaN
3   14013       NaN
4   14019       NaN
5   14018   14019.0
6   14022   14019.0
7   14023   14022.0
8   14021   14023.0
9   14020   14023.0
10  14014   14023.0
```

Comment: Hi @Corralien, thank you for your response. I appreciate that you are recommending me a much simpler method to find the max but i have to find out the max value based on those conditions only, if possible.  You can see the difference in values.

Comment: @r_goel. I updated my answer. Can you check if it fits to your need, please?

Answer (score 0):

answering my question, i got the result from the following code, hope it helps and any better code is welcomed.

```
def high_change(i, j) :
    last_hval = np.nan

    for a in range(i, j) :
        if  a == i : 
            last_hval = high_df1[a]
        elif high_df1[a] > high_df1[(a-1)] :
            last_hval = high_df1[a]
        else :
            last_hval

    return last_hval

def perc_change(src, lkbk) :  
    highest_high = []

    for i in range(len(src)) :
        if i < lkbk :
            highest_high.append(np.nan)
        else :
            highest_high.append(high_change(i-lkbk, i))
    
    return highest_high


df['h_h']  = pd.Series(perc_change(df, 5), dtype=float).round(2)
```